# Querying JSON data embedded in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I'd not used PostgreSQL for at least 10 years and was never very familiar with it. I now find myself having to deal with date + time strings embedded in a JSONB attribute in a PostrgreSQL database - and not with much success. I know nothing about querying JSON embedded in any relational database (except, of course, that it's *wrong* - but I can't fix that here).

If relevant, serverside is 13.10 and psql client I am using for testing is 9.2

I can retrieve the data:

```
SELECT id, ddata->'domain'->'created_at'
FROM schema.mytable
WHERE id=100

   id   |           ?column?
--------+---------------------------------
100     | "Tue, 13 Mar 2018 16:10:01 GMT"
```

However I can't workout how to get PostgreSQL to parse the value as a date.

Some of the things I've tried and the associated errors....

```
SELECT id, TO_DATE(ddata->'domain'->'created_at', '"Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS GMT"')
FROM myschema.mytable
WHERE id = 100

No function matches the given name and argument types

SELECT id, ddata->'domain'->'created_at'.datetime()
FROM myschema.mytable
WHERE id = 100

syntax error at or near "."


SELECT id, jsonb_path_query(ddata->'domain'->'created_at', '$[*].datetime("HH24:MI")')
FROM myschema.mytable
WHERE id = 100

ERROR:  invalid value "Tu" for "HH24"
DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.


SELECT id, jsonb_path_query(ddata->'domain'->'created_at', '$[*].datetime("Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS GMT")')
FROM myschema.mytable
WHERE id = 100

ERROR:  trailing characters remain in input string after datetime format
```

(the first attempt in block above looked promising if I could find a way of converting the type to a string. I couldn't find a way of doing that)

Ultimately I want to select records where this date is less than N days ago - but I can only do that if I can get PostgreSQL to parse the date.

A simplified version of the raw data in the attribute is:

```
{
  "domain": {
     "created_at": "Tue, 13 Mar 2018 16:10:01 GMT"
  }
}
```

UPDATE

Since posting I discovered the `->>` operator. However it doesn't help much; `TO_TIMESTAMP(ddata->'domain'->>'created_at', '"Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS"')` returns `0001-01-01 00:00:00+00 BC` for all values.

Comment: What happens when you cast it like so?   `(ddata->'domain'->>'created_at')::timestamptz`

Comment: Lookis like its working - now I just need to try that as a predicate.

Comment: 1) Postgres does not have a `TO_DATE` function. 2) You want to use a `psql` version that is equal to or greater then the server version. That should not make a difference in this case, bit it can become an issue.

Comment: 1) yes it does 2) already know about that and seen some of the fallout

Comment: 1) Hmm, I missed that here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html). I stand corrected.

Comment: You could alwys use a regex! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select ('{
  "domain": {
     "created_at": "Tue, 13 Mar 2018 16:10:01 GMT"
  }
}'::json
->'domain' ->> 'created_at')::date;
 date    
------------
 03/13/2018
```

For a `timestamp`:

```
select ('{
  "domain": {
     "created_at": "Tue, 13 Mar 2018 16:10:01 GMT"
  }
}'::json
->'domain' ->> 'created_at')::timestamptz;
       timestamptz       
-------------------------
 03/13/2018 09:10:01 PDT
```

First use `->` to extract the contents of the `'domain'` object as JSON then `->>` to extract the contents of `'created_at'` as `text`. Then use the `::date` cast to convert to a `date` or `timestamp(tz)` value.

Comment: Almost what Mike suggested above in comments - but the timestamp data type is more helpful than a date.

Comment: See update to answer for `timestamp` version.